# Making a vertcoin wallet with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cryptocurrency, wallet

I'm totally new in crypto currency and I wondered how we can make a wallet for vertcoin using python.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The editing of this post was not helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use already existing modules and use as per your need .

`Electrum-VTC`  is available on PyPI.

try installing using pip

`pip3 install Electrum-VTC`

if you want to do this from scratch then use a [SDK](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/reference/sdks/).
There are couple of tutorials which are very good which are [python](https://medium.com/algorand/generating-secure-crypto-wallets-and-accounts-with-python-b1b5b6cb51c4) centric